Generate reports with Power Automate
I want to know how to extract some rows from SQL and generate a report in TXT for SAP in Power Automate.  Does anyone know how to do it and can help me?  Thank you.
I made a query in SQL where I filtered the rows and created tables in HTML.  I want it to be organized in a TXT, but I have not been able to achieve it.
